# Tempfiles created by a resque worker are not deleted

Tags: ruby, resque

I tested this simple job, executed by a plain resque worker.

```
class Jobs::TestTempfile
  @queue = :test

  def self.perform
    Tempfile.open('foo') do |f|
      puts f.path
    end
  end
end
```

The temporary file created remains after the end of the job and even once the worker has been terminated (`kill -QUIT pid`).

I am aware the best practice is to unlink and close all `Tempfiles` but this seems like an issue anyway... Is anyone aware of some global solution to this? Or do I have to go through all the existing jobs to manually unlink `Tempfiles`.

I tested with `ruby 2.1` (but I'm positive the issue existed with `2.0`) and `resque 1.24.1`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> file = Tempfile.new('foo') puts file.path

works the same and deletes the temporary file once the interpreter exits.

Comment: I does not work with a Resque worker. I tested my Job with your syntax and the output is the same.

Comment: Even after you kill the worker, the temp file remains?

Answer (score 0):

Copying this from my GitHub answer:

Reading the Tempfile documentation:

> When a Tempfile object is garbage collected, or when the Ruby interpreter exits, its associated temporary file is 
>   automatically deleted. This means that’s it’s unnecessary to explicitly delete a Tempfile after use, though it’s good 
>   practice to do so: not explicitly deleting unused Tempfiles can potentially leave behind large amounts of tempfiles on 
>   the filesystem until they’re garbage collected. The existence of these temp files can make it harder to determine a 
>   new Tempfile filename.

It's possible that the GC is never run in a workers lifetime, which would leave all the tempfiles there.  It's probably best practice for your to unlink at the end of the `::perform` method.

You could also do something like:

```
class JobWithTempfiles
  class << self

    def new_tmpfile(name)
      file = Tempfile.new(name)
      @tmp_files ||= []
      @tmp_files << file
    end

    def perform_with_tmpfile_cleanup
       begin
         perform_without_tmpfile_cleanup
       ensure
         @tmp_files.each do |tmpfile|
           tmpfile.close
           tmpfile.unlink
         end
       end
     end
     alias_method_chain :perform, :tmpfile_cleanup
   end
end

class JobNeedingATmpFil < JobWithTempfiles
  def self.perform_without_tempfile_cleanup
    tmp_file = new_tmpfile("foo")
    # Do a bunch of stuff
  end
end
```